# I am getting this error when trying to upload the app to testflight "ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist"

Tags: ios, flutter, testflight

I have added the following code in the Info.plist

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Play using while you are hiking</string>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Please Allow the app to access the device camera</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Please Allow the app to access the device microphone</string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Privacy - Please Allow the app to handle your photos</string>
</dict>
```

I am creating the archive in Xcode and re distributing and still getting the error Missing Purpose String in Info.plist"

Answer (score 0):

As on Apple documentation for [NSAllowsArbitraryLoads](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity/nsallowsarbitraryloads)

> Important
> You must supply a justification during App Store review if you set the key’s value to YES, as described in Provide Justification for Exceptions. Use this key with caution because it significantly reduces the security of your app. In most cases, it’s better to upgrade your servers to meet the requirements imposed by ATS, or at least to use a narrower exception.

Comment: I have removed NSAllowsArbitraryLoads, still im getting the same error